# How to manually collapse a frame in Enlightment library

Tags: c, efl

I am using Enlightment library (C api) for user interface. I'd like to collapse the frame programatically, however the function seems not to work:

```
elm_frame_collapse_set(my_frame, EINA_TRUE);
```

When I trigger the function I get an error saying:

```
efl_ui_frame_collapse_set (2399) could not be resolved for class 'Elm.Box'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message saying you input Box object to frame API instead of Frame object.

Please check your code.

If you give right object to the API. please let me know the code.

Actually, it works well in my sample case.